# why $\left(\nu \nabla{u}\right)\nu=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \nu$ ?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, derivatives

I think the following question is one simple but I need your help :)

So, how can I prove that :

$$\left(\nu \nabla{u}\right)\nu=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \nu$$ ?

and second question, why:

$$\left(\nu \nabla{u}\right)\nu\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} =\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right)^{2} x \nu $$

These questions follow from Dirichlet's Problem:

\begin{cases}
-\Delta{u}=f(u)& \text{in $\Omega$} \\
u=0& \text{on $\Gamma$} \\
\end{cases}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ bounded domain with the border $\Gamma$ of $C^{1}$ class and $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continue function.

$\nu$ is exterior unit vector normal to the border $\Gamma$.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the definition
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} := \nabla u \cdot \nu$$
(think of directional derivatives).